# sending multi values to datagrid field Converter from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, infragistics

I am creating infragistics wpf grid at runtime.

in FieldLayoutInitialized i am creating unbound fields.

one sample unbound field is

```
UnboundField field = new UnboundField();

field.Name= "Testfield";

field.BindingPath = "Binding path";

FieldLayout fieldLayout;

fieldLayout.Fields.Add(field)
```

---

But my requirement is i have a field which is calculated one so for that i created converter. converter will return sum of two values.

A3 = A1+A2;

If it is from XAML file we can write like

```
<Textbox.Value>

<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConvertnameClass}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding Path="A1"/>
                    <Binding Path="A2"/>
                </MultiBinding>
</Textbox.Value>.
```

field.Converter = coverter class object;
field.ConverterParameter = ???;

if it is single binding we can send the
                field.BindingPath = "class prop value";

**how can i send multiple binding values to converter from code behind when it is creating run time.**

please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample that creates a multibinding in code behind

put this at your FieldLayoutInitialized event

```
private void FieldLayoutInitialized(object sender, FieldLayoutInitializedEventArgs e) {
  var fieldlayout = e.FieldLayout;

  UnboundField field = new UnboundField();
  field.Name = "Testfield";
  fieldlayout.Fields.Add(field);

  var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
  multiBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
  multiBinding.Converter = new MultiBindingConverter(); // implement IMultiValueConverter
  multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("A1"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
  multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("A2"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });

  field.Binding = multiBinding;
}
```

probably you must specify Source or RelativeSource for the two bindings

hope this helps (i used the 11.1 libs)